# What to do with MAX_JOIN_SIZE?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
$sqler = "SELECT artist.ArtistID, artist.ArtistName, artist.RegionID, artist_genre.ArtistID, artist_genre.GenreID, artist.Zip, artist.ImagePath, artist_video.ArtistID, artist_mentions.ArtistID, artist_press.ArtistID, artist_music.ArtistID 
FROM artist, artist_genre, artist_video, artist_mentions, artist_press, artist_music 
WHERE artist.RegionID IN($areaer) AND artist_genre.GenreID IN($genrer) AND artist.ArtistID = artist_genre.ArtistID $musik $video $omtale $presse GROUP BY artist.artistID";
```

When i try to run this Query nothing happend so i tested it in mysql and i got the error MAX_JOIN_SIZE that said i have to set SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1 but that doesn't change anything. I'm new to SQL and i think mabye i could optimize my query but i have no idea where to start. Would joining the tables help running the query lighter?

Comment: You are JOINING the tables  `FROM `artist, artist_genre, artist_video, artist_mentions, artist_press, artist_music` is the old JOIN syntax... using correct JOIN syntax so using IMPLICIT JOIN statements and correct indexing would result in a much better running query.... the MAX_JOIN_SIZE error is due to the the cause off using bad JOIN syntax and bad indexing.

Comment: What's in `$musik $video $omtale $presse`? Could you provide sample complete query without PHP variables?

Comment: They are all the same if not empty Video would look like "AND artist_video.ArtistID = artist.ArtistID"